# Custom XML Conversion from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, for-xml

I am running into an issue where I am having to do some custom encoding on some XML output that results from a SQL Server query.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Services xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AriesImportSchema.xsd">
   <ServiceLineItem _clientURNExt="ABCD0401712EFG" _siteName="Jerrys Dental Care" _staffLogin="asdasgasdsf" _contractName="17-18 Part A" serviceDate="2018-02-23" program="Ryan Black" primaryService="Oral Dental Care" secondaryService="Routine Treatment" subservice="Surgery Treatment" unitsOfService="1" rateForUnitOfService="18722.12" measurementUnit="Visit" totalCost="18722.12" />
</Services>
```

The Query to generate the data to be output to the ServiceLineItem tag as records is pretty straightforward:

```
select [_clientURNExt]
        , [_siteName]
        , [_staffLogin]
        , [_contractName]               
        , [serviceDate]
        , [program]
        , [primaryService]
        , [secondaryService]
        , [subservice]
        , 1 AS [unitsOfService]
        , [rateForUnitOfService] 
        , [measurementUnit]
        , [totalCost]
from ServiceLineItem
```

Comment: What is your issue?  You say you have one but you don't say what it is.  To ask a question that we can answer please update the above with what the expected output is and what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: also a style comment.  xml is case sensitive -- you really don't want camel case in SQL it is very hard to use.  I suggest all lower case with `_` if you really need a word seperator.

Comment: KenDazzo, please confirm that you really need the following: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AriesImportSchema.xsd"` at the root level.

Comment: The issue here is that I cannot find a way to flatten the XML appropriately. It seems as though I cannot get the XML to export in the correct format. If you look at the format that I need in the original post, it is flatter than what I can get just from exporting the query as XML. It doesn't look like each column tag is closed - it looks like just the <ServiceLineItem> and <Services> tag are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select [_clientURNExt] as [@_clientURNExt]      
from ServiceLineItem 
FOR XML PATH ('ServiceLineItem'),ROOT('Services');
```

Comment: I think you need to include all the attributes in the select list

Comment: I know, but this should be sufficient to figure it out.  I 'm here trying to help people, but I'm not going to do all their work.

Comment: hmm... any article or book at all on this should be sufficient to figure it out.  That is why I asked what problem they were having in the question comments.  You actually didn't show how to do one of the harder parts with the name space declare but not use.  This is what I expect is his actual problem.

Comment: That's why I asked it explicitly, the namespaces pertaining issue...